# Removing number on ToC, but maintaining the position of the text

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I am trying to remove the numbering on the table of content (and on the section too) but maintaining the position of the name of the section, like in following the figure:

[image]

And then it would looks like:

[image]

I've tried `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`, but it change the position of the name of the section.
The `\section*{name of the section}` removes it from ToC.

EDIT:
As requested, the preamble (I've changed to make smaller):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{ragged2e}     
\usepackage{tocloft}            
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{1}}            
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{-}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\fontsize{12}{12}}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{\textbf{SUMMARY}}}

\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{12}{12}\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{12}{12}\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{12}\sffamily\bfseries}

\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0em}{2.3em}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{35pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecnumwidth{35pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecnumwidth{35pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example - a small document - that replicates a ToC that you display? That way we can see which packages you're using, what you're preamble looks like, what `\documentclass` you're using... all of these things may influence the solution you're looking for.

Comment: As Werner say, exactly how do you create the un numbered items in the toc? One method: `\section*{Test}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\numberline{}Test}`

Comment: The daleif method worked!! Thanks a lot Werner and daleif, and the other guys who answered too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With every starred sectional unit, add the contents entry manually, together with a `\numberline{}` prefix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{1}}            
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{-}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\fontsize{12}{12}}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{\textbf{SUMMARY}}}

\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0em}{2.3em}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{35pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecnumwidth{35pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecnumwidth{35pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\section*{Another section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Another section}
\subsection*{Another subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\numberline{}Another subsection}
\subsubsection*{Another subsubsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\numberline{}Another subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

This can be automated, using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), for example. Here's how to do it for `\section`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\oldsection*{#3}% \section*
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}#3}}% \section*{}
       {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}#2}}}% \section*[]{}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}% \section
       {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}}% \section[]{}
}
```

A similar approach would hold for other sectional units.

Answer (score 6):

I would wait for a better answer but before the LaTeX wizards come up with something magic you can try this (using the `titletoc` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newlength{\mytocsep}
\setlength{\mytocsep}{1.5em}
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{\mytocsep}}{}
    {\titlerule*[0.5pc]{-}\contentspage}
\newcommand{\myunnumberedsection}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
\section*{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\myunnumberedsection{No Numbered}
\section{Try again}
\end{document}
```

I.e. I define a new command called `\myunnumberedsection` that does what you asked. Adjust the value of `\mytocsep` to set the horizontal sep in the ToC.
[image: Unnumbered section with proper alignment]

Answer (score 3):

With `KOMA-Script` you can achieve this with the `\addchap` and `\addsec` commands. Here an MWE.

```
\documentclass[
    toc=flat,   % all numbers should be aligned left
    toc=indenttextentries,
        ]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{subsection 1}
    \subsubsection{subsubsection 1}
    \section{section 2}
    \addsec{section 3}
    \addsec{section 4}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP explicitly requested that the alignment of the titles are maintained in the ToC.

Comment: Add KOMA-Script option `toc=indenttextentries` to get the desired result in TOC.

Comment: @Werner, sorry, I was too fast this morning and just forgot about the second requirement. I have adapted my answer accordingly as was already [commented by esdd](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299074/removing-number-on-toc-but-maintaining-the-position-of-the-text/299075#comment723921_299075). Thank you for that.